# NoMethodError: relative_url_root when deploying rails app on tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, deployment, jruby

I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://thenice.tumblr.com/post/133345213/deploying-a-rails-application-in-tomcat-with-jruby-a) to deploy my jruby app on tomcat, but yet it always ends with:

```
--- Backtrace
    NoMethodError: undefined method `relative_url_root=' for ActionController::Base:Class
          send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097
```

Tried either with tomcat 6 and 7.

My jruby version is 1.6.5 and I use Rails 3.1 (too fresh perhaps ?)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had the same problem, and it was tracked down to the new version jruby-rack (1.1.1 IIRC). We downgraded to 1.0.10 and the problem went away. I'm not sure what the "root" of the problem was though.

Comment: How exactly did you downgrade to 1.0.10? I assume you're using warbler too?

Comment: You want to make sure that warbler is packaging the 1.0.10 version of jruby-rack. This can change depending on how you're managing your gems. In a Rails 3 application, you can specify version of jruby-rack to use in your gem file.