# Error pages (500.html, 404.html, etc) not being rendered in rails/jruby environment

Tags: tomcat, jruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm completely baffled by the following issue:

1. Rails 3.2 application on Tomcat with jruby 1.6.5.1
2. When an error is triggered, (any error) the page eventually times out with "Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset."

I obviously expect either a stack trace or public/500.html to be rendered depending on the environment config. The application performs *exactly* as I expect when doing local development on Mac or Windows. The Tomcat environment this application gets deployed to is probably not at fault (we run hundreds of rails apps in similar configurations).

The public/*.html files are being packaged up in the .war file for deployment as they should be.

Other than not rendering errors, the application functions just fine.

Where can I even start debugging this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is to downgrade to jruby-rack version 1.0.10, similar to this issue [which I also answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151053/nomethoderror-relative-url-root-when-deploying-rails-app-on-tomcat). It looks like there are multiple issues with the latest versions of jruby-rack on Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

This flag was also not working for me on JRuby 1.7.26, Rails 3.0.20, Tomcat 8 / Java 8:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

I ended up monkey patching the Rails library. It appears there is something funny with the 'request.local?' call on line 67 (actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb) when running in Tomcat.

I changed this line from:

```
if @consider_all_requests_local || request.local?
```

to

```
if @consider_all_requests_local
```

My reasoning for doing this is I just set the consider_all_request_local flag manually when developing so the auto fallback on the loopback address is moot.

Comment: A proxy server is likely the cause of the request.local? failure here.